# Writing on JSON file writes but didn't save it

Tags: javascript, json

Is it normal on writing into JSON File but not saving it? if so, how do you actually save it if its done? After I write into JSON file and read it again... it came back to normal...

```
module.exports = {
    data: async function() {
        const fs = require('fs');
        let obj;


        fs.readFile('test.json', 'utf8', function readFileCallBack(err, data) {
            if (err) console.log(err);
            else if (data !== undefined) {
                obj = JSON.parse(data);
                obj.table.push({ id: 1, name: 'test' });
                json = JSON.stringify(obj);
                console.log(obj); //{ table: [{id:1, name: 'test'}] }
                fs.writeFile('test.json', json, readFileCallBack);
            }
        });


        fs.readFile('test.json', 'utf8', function readFileCallBack(err, data) {
            if (err) console.log(err);
            else if (data !== undefined) {
                obj = JSON.parse(data);
                console.log(obj); //{ table: [] }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

My JSON File:

```
{
    "table": [
        
    ]
}
```

Is there someting to do with `localstorage.setItem()` to actually save it?

Comment: JS is asynchronous, both of your fs.readFile gets executed in parallel. read from your fs.writeFile callback

Answer (score 0):

Since JS is asynchronous in nature, both of your fs.readFile functions will be executed in parallel. So, you want to update the data that is there in the JSON file. To handle asynchronous code you can use callbacks or promises. Here is an example using promise ( async/await )

```js
const fs = require("fs");
const util = require("util");

const defaultObj = {
    table: []
};

const readFilePromise = util.promisify(fs.readFile);
const writeFilePromise = util.promisify(fs.writeFile);

async function readFromJSON() {
    const data = await readFilePromise('test.json', { encoding: "utf-8" });
    return data.toString("utf-8");
}

function writeToJSON(json) {
    return writeFilePromise('test.json', json);
}

async function getData() {
    let data = await readFromJSON(); // read from JSON file
    const obj = data ? JSON.parse(data) : defaultObj;
    obj.table.push({ id: 1, name: 'test' });
    const json = JSON.stringify(obj);
    await writeToJSON(json); // update the data
    return obj;
}

module.exports = {
    data: getData
};
```